# this app is associated with a different google account

Tags: google-play-store, android-10

I am using 5-6 gmail accounts on my android phone.
There are situations when I access [Google Files app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files) on my laptop and then on phone it shows that I am signed in to play store via different account.

I want to make sure on laptop when I open Google files app and install an app that installs app on my mobile I am on same Google account.

Comment: How would the laptop know what concurrent account on the phone is currently active? Why should/would it care? Most importantly, what corrective action would you design into the systems to take care of a decidedly personal, decidedly rare, user case?

Comment: I have 2 Google accounts on my phone, and AFAIK, you can (and have to) switch the account manually on both the Play Store app and web version.